# como hacer la siguiente consulta en mysql, ayuda

Tags: sql

Buen día, tengo un problema para realizar una consulta en mysql debido a que soy totalmente inexperto. Me gustaría saber si alguien me puede ayudar a conseguir lo que necesito. En la imagen está toda la explicación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: De preferencia que las consultas sean texto es mas facil para hacer pruebas

Comment: el * en el select te trae todos los campos (incluidos los del join) para filtrar campos debes ponerlos explicitos ejempo `SELECT alumnos.id_alumno, alumnos.nombre` ... para reemplazar el id de universidad por el nombre tendras que hacer otro join con la tabla de universidad. en tu caso se repite id_alumno pues hay un `alumnos.id_alumno` y un `promedios.id_alumno` (que trae el join)

Comment: Comentario que no responde la pregunta: por favor pon tu pregunta, el código y los logs de errores que correspondan, como texto plano. Replicar cualquier cosa usando imágenes es dispendioso.

Comment: Mira [ask] <- ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] <- ACA para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 2):

Estas muy cerca de lo que quieres:

```
SELECT id_alumno, nombre, universidad, AVG(calificacion)
FROM alumno JOIN universidad ON id_universidad
    JOIN calificaciones ON id_alumno
GROUP BY id_alumno
```

Answer (score 2):

Por lo que entendí y usando inner join creo que sería más o menos así:

```
select a.nombre, u.nombre, a.ciudad, avg(c.calificacion) as promedio  from alumno a
inner join univerisdad on(a.id_universidad=u.id_universidad)
inner join calificaciones c on (a.id_lumno = c.id_alumno)
group by id_alumno
```

Answer (score 2):

Creo que es algo similar a esto:

```
SELECT a.id_alumno,
       a.nombre,
       a.ciudad,
       u.universidad,
       (select AVG(c.calificacion) from calificaciones c where c.id_alumno = a.id_alumno) as promedio
FROM alumno a 
JOIN universidad on u.id_universidad = a.id_universidad
```

o también del modo que ejemplificaron los demás:

```
SELECT a.id_alumno,
       a.nombre,
       a.ciudad,
       u.universidad,
       AVG(c.calificacion) as promedio
FROM alumno a 
JOIN universidad u on u.id_universidad = a.id_universidad
JOIN calificaciones c on c.id_alumno = a.id_alumnno 
group by a.alumno
```